# How do I use non-regular variant of a font in Ubuntu?

Tags: fonts, configuration, system-settings

How do I use non-regular variant of a font in Ubuntu?

Simply stating, I was trying to use light variant of a font. However, I couldn't. Every time I select those light variant, Ubuntu reluctantly used the same regular one.

For example, Today, I was trying to use `Dosis` font. When I choose this using Ubuntu-Tweak (or Unity-Tweak-Tool), Ubuntu selected the light one. I wanted to use Medium one, since that was giving more contrast. But selecting Dosis-Medium gave the save light rendering!!

Lastly, I tried using `fonts.conf` in `.config/fontconfig` directory. I've put these lines in that file. Putting these lines forces Ubuntu to display medium variant, but then Every Dosis fonts become **Medium**. There is no way to use **Light** variant anymore.

```
  <match>
    <test name="family"><string>Dosis</string></test>
    <edit name="style" mode="assign" binding="strong">
      <string>Medium</string>
    </edit>
  </match>
```

In short, How can I select or use different variant of a font in Ubuntu. A solution using `fonts.conf` is also okay.

**Output of `fc-list 'Dosis'`**

```
    /usr/share/fonts/opentype/dosis/Dosis-Light.otf: Dosis:style=Light
    /usr/share/fonts/opentype/dosis/Dosis-SemiBold.otf: Dosis:style=SemiBold
    /usr/share/fonts/opentype/dosis/Dosis-Bold.otf: Dosis:style=Bold
    /usr/share/fonts/opentype/dosis/Dosis-Book.otf: Dosis:style=Book
    /usr/share/fonts/opentype/dosis/Dosis-ExtraBold.otf: Dosis:style=ExtraBold
    /usr/share/fonts/opentype/dosis/Dosis-ExtraLight.otf: Dosis:style=ExtraLight
    /usr/share/fonts/opentype/dosis/Dosis-Medium.otf: Dosis:style=Medium
```

**Output of `fc-match 'Dosis'`**

```
    Dosis-Medium.otf: "Dosis" "Medium"
```

**Output of `fc-match 'Dosis-Medium'`**

```
    Dosis-Medium.otf: "Dosis" "Medium"
```

Screenshot of Dosis font selecting light variant:

[image: Dosis using light variant]

If I use `fonts.conf`, all dosis become same

[image]

Comment: Have you tried copying the font file you want to use to another name and then using that one?  E.G. `sudo cp /usr/share/fonts/opentype/dosis/Dosis-Light.otf /usr/share/fonts/opentype/anwar.otf` and then using font `anwar`?

Comment: No, I haven't. But as far as i know, font file name does nothing if font file include name within

Comment: @AnwarShah you might as well try.

Comment: @Tim That didn't do anything

Answer (score 1):

Testing here using Ubuntu 14.04, Ubuntu Tweak and the fonts-dosis package works. Selecting light, medium, bold all show different results. Although the light and medium look similar at 11pt even with my sharp eyes.

My desktop did however close itself and restart in a rather aggressive manor once a new font selection was made and I had to log back in again.

So I would delete your `font.conf` file and make your selections making sure to note how the font looks in the bottom font preview box of the selector window and not the distracting larger fonts in the list. Increase the size as needed. Select and then restart.

Comment: That was I saying. Medium and Light are exactly the same

Comment: They're not exactly the same, although they might look the same at certain resolutions and certain sizes.

Comment: I have tested today with another font. when light variation is present, it picks up that one instead of medium variant. I checked this by setting medium variant as font, and then deleting the light one. after deletion and running `fc-cache` fonts immediately changed to medium.

Comment: Interesting test. Please report it as a bug https://help.ubuntu.com/community/ReportingBugs including all the details here. I do report it working on 14.04 Ubuntu so include that detail too.

Comment: Will do in a while. I think, you also test this and support the bug if you can.

Answer (score 0):

Fonts usually come compressed in several files, depending on the variations it includes: light, bold, medium, italic, italic-bold, etc.

If you're using a new font (e.g., a font not regularly packed in Ubuntu), you should install all its variations so you don't find any problems using them later.